# logging into instagram using python with mechanize

Tags: python, instagram, mechanize

I have just started using python and mechanize and I need some help understanding why this will not work.

```
import mechanize
username = "<username>"
password = "<password>"

ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0 (compatible;)'

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-Agent', ua), ('Accept', '*/*')]

br.open("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
br.select_form(nr=0)
br[username] = username
br[password] = password
result = br.submit().read()
f = open('output.html','w')
f.write(result)
f.close()
```

the error it throws is:
FormNotFoundError: no form matching nr 0
and I cannot figure out what the correct form id is. Even after attempting to list all forms using the following:

```
print("\n Printing all forms on page...\n")
for form in br.forms():
    print("Form Name:", form.name)
    print form
print("\n Done printing forms...\n")
```

the list of forms is empty. How can I find what the forms id is if mechanize cannot see the form itself?

Comment: you may want to look at splinter with phantomjs, it might be a better fit for what you're trying to accomplish.  Unless you're willing to reverse engineer the javascript, in which case just use requests.

Answer (score 0):

To select the first form, you could do this:

```
br.form = list(br.forms())[0]
```

then, to enter the username and password:

```
br.form["username"] = username
br.form["password"] = password
```

and then finally, to submit:

```
req = br.submit()
```

edit: just noticed you said the list of forms would return empty. This is most likely be because the site is using javascript. You might have better luck with selenium.

Good luck!